# i dont want my contact.php redirect me to a blank site, i want to show a message without going out the web

Tags: php, contact-form

i have a contact.php form that works very well, but i have a problem with that form, the messages like alerts, etc, are showing in the file contact.php itself, i want that when i hit the "Send" button, the php puts a eccho to say the message without leaving the site.

Heres my contact.php

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "natestale@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Nuevo contacto de Sitio web";
    function died($error) {
        // Mensaje de error
        echo "Disculpas, pero ha ocurrido un(os) error(es) con lo datos del formulario. ";
        echo "El o los errores son los siguientes.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Por favor corrija los errores.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }
    // validacion de campos
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('Disculpas, pero ha ocurrido un(os) error(es) al enviar el formulario.');       
    }
    $name = $_POST['name']; // obligatorio
    $email = $_POST['email']; // obligatorio
    $website = $_POST['website']; // no obligatorio
    $prioritycase = $_POST['prioritycase']; // no obligatorio
    $asunto = $_POST['asunto']; // no obligatorio
    $message = $_POST['message']; // obligatorio
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
    $error_message .= 'La direccion de E-mail es incorrecta.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'EL nombre no es un nombre Valido.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$website)) {
    $error_message .= 'La url no es valida.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($message) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'El comentario no parece estar completo.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
    $email_message .= "Nombre: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Website: ".clean_string($website)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Mensaje: ".clean_string($message)."\n";
// estructura del correo
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=http://www.redpandastudio.tk" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/css/contacto.css" />
<!-- incluimos nuestro mensaje de agradecimiento -->

<?php
}
?>
```

And here is my website with the contact form working.

http://redpandastudio.tk/

Comment: If you don't want the form to actually submit, use AJAX, otherwise, you can submit to the same page and pass an `error` parameter, and in the page, first thing - check if that parameter error is set - display the error.

Comment: How can i use AJAX to submit?

Comment: google: "submit form ajax" and you'll find plenty of examples

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to put your validation from your file contact.php into the file where you have the form itself. When pressing submit make it post to the same file. Moreover, add to your validation logic this line:

// to find out if submit btn was pressed - which means that somebody clicked the button

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
.... 
}
```

Another option is to use $SESSION. How to use Sessions for validation is very nicely explained [here](http://php.find-info.ru/php/014/webdbapps2-CHP-10-SECT-3.html).